# Facebook App Configuration

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

My app has been working fine for a long time but now this error comes up during the facebook authentication. Any suggestions to solve this issue

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Answer (score 0):

You must put your app domains in "App Domains" field (Basic Info tab) and set your "Site URL" in "Website with Facebook Login" tab.